# Flexbox width broken in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of items. Each list item contains a radio button of an unknown width and a dropdown list that I would like to take up the rest of the width of the container. My code works in Chrome, but not in IE11. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="project-list">
         <div class="radio-selector">
               ...code for radio button...
         </div>
         <div class="dropdown-selector">
               <select class="dropdown">
                     ...options...
               </select>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my css:

```
li.project-list{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.dropdown-selector {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
.dropdown{
    width:100%;
}
```

The flexbox code was generated using this site: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Any help is appreciated!

**edit**

Ah sorry, the dropdown is completely shrunk in width instead of taking up the remaining space.

Comment: What's the symptom of "doesn't work" in IE?

Comment: Ah sorry, the dropdown is completely shrunk in width instead of taking up the remaining space. Or is is full width and not inline with the other element.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to reproduce the problem. Consider posting a complete example and demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net).. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into jsfiddle.net and it works fine in IE 11 and Edge. 
https://jsfiddle.net/dsd61ets/

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fact then that i'm using a modal or external libraries (kendo and bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

When defining the flex shorthand, you have declared that the content can shrink, the same as `flex-shrink: 1`. Have you tried:

```
.dropdown-selector{
    flex: auto;
}
```

I think IE11 also has some problems with the flex shorthand. You could also try using:

```
.dropdown-selector{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

I don't have a windows PC around to test IE on unfortunately, but [this](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) is a useful reference for IE11 Flex bugs.

Comment: I've tries both solutions and neither seems to work for me :/

Comment: Just setting `display: flex` on the child of the flex container was enough to fix this for me on IE11.