# Flexbox min-width broken in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I use the library [react-toastify](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify) to show toasts in my application. By default the toast has `width: 320px`. Since this is sometimes not enough space for a word and part of that word is not displayed, I tried to resize the toast by using this css:

```
div.toast-resize {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

This works in Chrome, but unfortunately not in IE 11. In IE the toasts have always the `min-width`. I think the reason is the use of flexbox by toastify. Unfortunately neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665332/flexbox-width-broken-in-ie) nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562755/flexbox-ie10-width-issues) workaround worked. I created the following example. The `.Toastify*`-Rules can't be changed, `div.toast-resize` is my own rule.

How can I make this look equal in IE and Chrome?

```css
.Toastify__toast-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 320px;
}
.Toastify__toast {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Toastify__toast--success {
  background: #07bc0c;
}
.Toastify__toast-body {
  flex: 1 1;
}

div.toast-resize {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="Toastify">
      <div class="Toastify__toast-container Toastify__toast-container--top-right toast-resize">
        <div class="Toastify__toast Toastify__toast--success">
          <div class="Toastify__toast-body" role="alert"
            >Very long text with loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Toastify__toast Toastify__toast--success">
          <div class="Toastify__toast-body" role="alert">Short text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run your code in chrome, both div have the max-width of 500px. I thought your idea was in this example, that the first div stops growing when reaching the max-width and break and the second one stay at the min-width of 100px because it has enough space to display the text within? At the moment both have 500px width

Comment: At the moment, the width of the longest element is the width of all elements. Maybe it really is easier to set the width fix to 500px.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min-width` in the `.toast-resize` class equals to that of `max-width`. It forces the div to be exactly 500px in every devices.

```
div.toast-resize {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to have the toast the same size, as the text is very short sometimes. But if there is no better solution, maybe I should do that.

Comment: If you use `width:auto;` then it will take the `min-width` first on the top of `max-width`